# “Old-Style ASCII Property List” to Json in Swift

Tags: json, swift, nsdictionary

I have a string that looks like following:

```
{\n    \"account_no\" = \"5675672343244\";\n    \"account_kind\" =     {\n        \".tag\" = test,\n    };\n    country = US;\n    disabled = 0;\n    email = \"test@gmail.com\";\n    \"email_verified\" = 1;\n    \"is_paired\" = 0;\n    };\n}"
```

It is similar to NSDictionary when it is printed as description to the console. Especially

- some strings are in quotes, some are not. See `country = US;\n`
- they use k-v notation with `=`. E.g. `key = value`
- they use delimiter `;`

Unfortunately I do not have the original object that created the string. I have only the string itself.

My goal is to transform it to a valid JSON string representation, or alternatively back to a NSDictionary. Should be done in Swift 5. I failed so far in doing so, does anyone has sample code that would help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description of an `NSDictionary` produces an [“Old-Style ASCII Property List”](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/OldStylePlists/OldStylePLists.html), and [`PropertyListSerialization`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/propertylistserialization) can be used to convert that back to an object.

Note that the format is ambiguous. As an example, `1234` can be both a number or a string consisting of decimal digits only. So there is no guarantee to get the exact result back.

Example:

```
let desc = "{\n    \"account_no\" = \"5675672343244\";\n    \"account_kind\" =     {\n        \".tag\" = test;\n    };\n    country = US;\n    disabled = 0;\n    email = \"test@gmail.com\";\n    \"email_verified\" = 1;\n    \"is_paired\" = 0;\n}"

do {
    let data = Data(desc.utf8)
    if let dict = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, format: nil) as? NSDictionary {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: .prettyPrinted)
        print(String(data: json, encoding: .utf8)!)
    } else {
        print("not a dictionary")
    }
} catch {
    print("not a valid property list:", error)
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "country" : "US",
  "email_verified" : "1",
  "is_paired" : "0",
  "account_no" : "5675672343244",
  "email" : "test@gmail.com",
  "disabled" : "0",
  "account_kind" : {
    ".tag" : "test"
  }
}
```

(I had to “fix” the description string to make it a valid property list: "test" was followed by a comma instead of a semicolon, and there was an unbalanced `}` at the end of the string.)

Comment: Thanks! Yes that is what I was looking for, and thanks for the proper name “Old-Style ASCII Property List” - I was unable to find it otherwise.